# Deserialize JSON with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I build a navigation tree and save the structure using this function in an array

```
function parseTree(html) {
   var nodes = [];
   html.parent().children("div").each(function () {
      var subtree = $(this).children("div");
      var item = $(this).find(">span");
      if (subtree.size() > 0)
          nodes.push([item.attr("data-pId"), item.attr("data-id"), parseTree(subtree)]);
      else
          nodes.push(item.attr("data-pId"), item.attr("data-id"));
  });
  return nodes;
}
```

Then I serialize the data

```
var tree = $.toJSON(parseTree($("#MyTree").children("div")));
```

Get this array

```
[
    ["881150024","881150024",
        [
         "994441819","881150024",
         "214494418","881150024"
        ]
    ],
    ["-256163399","-256163399",
        [
            "977082012","-256163399",
            "-492694206","-256163399",
            [
                "1706814966","-256163399",
                    ["-26481618","-256163399"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

And send it by ajax

```
             $.ajax({
                url: "Editor/SerializeTree",
                type: "POST",
                data: { tree: tree },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("OK");
                }
            });
```

**Question: How do I Deserialize this JSON with JavaScriptSerializer in C#?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it seems like you've got an array of nodes and each node has a set of strings or another array of nodes, right? The first thing you could do is just deserialize this to a `List<object>` like so:

```
string treeData = "..."; // The JSON data from the POST
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<object> tree = js.Deserialize <List<object>>(treeData);
```

This will turn your JSON into a list of objects, though you'll need to manually figure out what is what (if each object a string or another `List<object>`).

Generally, though, it helps to have some kind of class or struct to represent the "schema" for the the data you are giving the serializer, but it's a bit more work than the above.

In this instance, you'd need your input data to be an actual JSON object rather than just an array. Say you have this JSON (based on the above data):

```
{id: "root", children: [
  {id: "881150024"},
  {id: "881150024", children: [
    {id: "994441819"}, {id: "881150024"}]},
    {id: "-256163399"},
    {id: "-256163399", children: [            
    {id: "-492694206"},
      {id: "-256163399", children: [
        {id: "1706814966"},
        {id: "-256163399", children: [
          {id: "-26481618"}, {id: "-256163399"}]}
]}]}]}
```

If you have a class like this:

```
public class Node
{
  public String id;
  public List<Node> children;
}
```

You can then do something like:

```
string treeData = "..."; // The JSON data from the POST
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Node root = js.Deserialize<Node>(treeData);
```

That will be much easier to work with in code.

Comment: Well described! I used the second solution. I just needed to fix this line  List<Node> root = js.Deserialize<List<Node>>(tree); Thank a lot. It was my first script with deserialization :-)

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account answer by @_rusty.

In MVC3 it is possible to bing JSON data into actions, so your controller code would be very simple

```
[HttpPost]
public void SerializeTree(IList<Node> tree)
{
    // tree is deserialized JSON here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I use MVC2 right now. When I update it to 3th version I will try this beautiful solution. :-)

Comment: @podeig, I would not wait :) and use MvcFutures to get required solution. It is very simple and beautiful, check this http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For those rare few of us still using VB.Net here and there:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

'wsvcResponse<string> contains the following JSON object: { "foo":"bar", "foo2": { "bar2": "foobar" } }
Dim jsSerializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim jsonObject As List(Of Object) = jsSerializer.Deserialize(Of Object)(wsvcResponse)
Dim foo As String = jsonObject("foo").ToString  ' "bar"
Dim bar2 As String = jsonObject("foo2")("bar2").ToString ' "foobar"
```

Comment: Really newbie question - in the `Dim jsonObject As List(Of Object)`, do I replace `Object` with a Class I've created, or just leave it as `Object`?

Comment: I'm using the generic Object class (which is rare for me as I generally use explicit types) mainly because I couldn't find a better way to get the results of the Deserialize() method casted. My initial instinct was : ".Deserialize(Of List(of string))(wsvcResposne) but I couldn't get that working as expected.