# Convert JSON String to JSON Object

Tags: vb.net, json

I have a JSON response from a web service that I need to be converted to an object then to an array. My response is similar to the one below:

```
  {"status":{"error":"NO","code":"200","description":"none","message":"Request ok"},"geolocation":{"lat":"38.89515","lng":"-77.0310"},"stations":[{"country":"United States","regPrice":"0.00","midPrice":"0.00","prePrice":"0.00","streetAddress":"1401, I St NW","ID":"1900","lat":"38.901440","lng":"-77.032127","stationName":"Shell","logo":"http:\/\/www.nyneaxis.com\/logo\/stations\/noLogo.png","state":"District of Columbia","city":"Washington D.C.","regDate":null,"midDate":null,"preDate":null,"distance":"0.7"},{"country":"United States","regPrice":"0.00","midPrice":"0.00","prePrice":"0.00","streetAddress":"2116-2150, M St NW","ID":"13029","lat":"38.905201","lng":"-77.048103","stationName":"Exxon","logo":"http:\/\/www.nyneaxis.com\/logo\/stations\/noLogo.png","state":"District of Columbia","city":"Washington D.C.","regDate":null,"midDate":null,"preDate":null,"distance":"1.9"}]}
```

I am doing this is VB.NET within a console for now. Basically I am trying to create a simple way to test my API calls and output the information. What I am trying to accomplish is having to loop through the JSON array and list the stations. I have never done this in VB.NET before and would like some help. I have been reading about deserialization but do not understand it.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good library for .NET called Json.NET  that's useful for doing this kind of stuff http://json.codeplex.com/

there are a bunch of examples, mostly C# though.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Json.NET

```
Dim ThisToken as JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JToken)(JSonString)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx has a detailed "How to" on this topic

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0+, you can user [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) Deserialize method, check:
[Deserialize JSON with JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937450/deserialize-json-with-javascriptserializer?rq=1)

Note: Keep in mind that you need to have a .NET class with all the properties of the JSON object to deserialize.