# Cant get my head around parsing JSON in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing

Can someone help me out?
I'm trying to parse this JSON output that the cloudstack API is giving me in vb.net, but i cant get my head around it

The json output from the cloudstack is :

```
{
    "listcapacityresponse": {
        "count": 6,
        "capacity": [
            {
                "type": 8,
                "zoneid": "f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045",
                "zonename": "DBXCP1",
                "capacityused": 6,
                "capacitytotal": 18,
                "percentused": "33.33"
            },
            {
                "type": 0,
                "zoneid": "f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045",
                "zonename": "DBXCP1",
                "capacityused": 27246198784,
                "capacitytotal": 97078222080,
                "percentused": "28.07"
            },
            {
                "type": 1,
                "zoneid": "f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045",
                "zonename": "DBXCP1",
                "capacityused": 13500,
                "capacitytotal": 52800,
                "percentused": "25.57"
            },
            {
                "type": 5,
                "zoneid": "f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045",
                "zonename": "DBXCP1",
                "capacityused": 3,
                "capacitytotal": 12,
                "percentused": "25"
            },
            {
                "type": 6,
                "zoneid": "f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045",
                "zonename": "DBXCP1",
                "capacityused": 14978383872,
                "capacitytotal": 106308304896,
                "percentused": "14.09"
            },
            {
                "type": 3,
                "zoneid": "f26c2094-f2ca-4951-9265-a3f036e7f045",
                "zonename": "DBXCP1",
                "capacityused": 92190801920,
                "capacitytotal": 1099511627776,
                "percentused": "8.38"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to be able to break this down so i can easily and reliably get the 'capacity used', 'capacity total' and 'percent used' of each type and assign these values to an array or individual variables in vb.net.

I can opt to receive this same output in XML, but not sure how to parse that in vb.net either. Which would be easier?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JSON String to JSON Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904522/convert-json-string-to-json-object)

Comment: I've looked at that, but cant get my head around the examples there.
I'm after someone throwing some advice my way specifically related to the JSON above, so I can hopefully figure out what i'm doing :)

Comment: How are you getting this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, please forgive me, my VB.NET is rusty to say the least, I'm transliterating from C#.  My suggestion is almost always JSON over XML.  The tools at your disposal for handling JSON are many.  You need to install the NuGet Package Json.NET (or any other JSON deserializer, however I coded my examples against Json.NET) into your project.  From there you have two options.  The first, dynamic typing:

```
Dim dynamicObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(jsonString)
Dim capacity = dynamicObj("listcapacityresponse")("capacity")
For Each subObj as Object in capacity
    Console.WriteLine(subObj("capacityused"))
Next
```

This is very basic, and simply writes out the value.  You can do with this as you please.

Your other option is to create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) and deserialize to a fully defined object.  The DTO should look similar to the following:

```
Public Class Capacity
    public type As Integer = Nothing
    public zoneid As String = Nothing
    public zonename As String = Nothing
    public capacityused As Long = Nothing
    public capacitytotal AS Long = Nothing
    public percentused As String = Nothing
End Class

Public Class Listcapacityresponse
    public count As Integer = Nothing
    public capacity As List(Of Capacity) = Nothing
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    public listcapacityresponse As Listcapacityresponse = Nothing
End Class
```

Then your code to access the values would be as follows:

```
Dim dtoObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(jsonString)
For Each stuff As Capacity in dtoObj.Listcapacityresponse.capacity
    Console.WriteLine(stuff.capacityused)
Next
```

The big benefit of using a DTO is that you can easily use LINQ to access the values, like this:

```
Dim capacities = From stuff in dtoObj.Listcapacityresponse.capacity Select stuff.capacityused
```

I hope this gets you started down the road to using Json.NET and understanding the use of DTO and Dynamic types.  Please forgive my horrendous VB.NET as I'm a C# guy.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that DTO stands for Data Transfer Object?

Comment: Careful:  if a list is empty, CloudStack usually returns a null and not a zero-sized array.