# I have a Json array , Just I want to get value from array

Tags: json, vb.net

Please see the below code,How to get value from using VB.net {"page":{ "Pagenames":"Home.aspx","querystrings":[{ "key":"linfo", "experssion": "^1-9a-z", "IsEncrypted":"True"}

Comment: You cant, thats not valid json. Also what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON String to JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904522/convert-json-string-to-json-object)

Answer (score -1):

There is JObject Parse function which can help you here

```
Dim json As String = line

        Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
```

M